# Can an argument be "undergirded"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, synonyms

When writing an argumentative text (like a comment), it is common to support one's arguments with further explanations and examples.

Can this process of supporting the main point of the argument be called "undergirding"?

For example:

> "To further undergird my argument I would like to examine..."

Comment: The verb is used exactly as used in your example.

Comment: It could, but I'm not sure I would trust the argument of anyone using that word.

Comment: Neither explanations nor examples constitute undergirding (nor underpinning).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can undergird an argument, in the sense of supporting it.

***[Undergird](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undergird)*** is not a very common term but it is currently used in its figurative sense, as noted by Merriam Webster in the following  extract:

> The English verb gird means, among other things, "to encircle or bind with a flexible band." When undergird first entered English in the 16th century, it meant "to make secure underneath," as by passing a rope or chain underneath something (such as a ship). ***That literal sense has long since fallen out of use, but in the 19th century undergird picked up the figurative "strengthen" or "support" sense that we still use.***

You can find a few usage examples in [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22undergird%20an%20argument%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).

Comment: It's common in essays, good news writing, academic writing etc. But your usual butcher might not use it.

Comment: The issue is that it usually means to provide the *basis* for something. The asker appears to be using it to refer to providing *additional support,* which is somewhat different.

Comment: @alphabet: That's a spurious distinction. Merriam-Webster is as AmE-oriented as any, and their definition (for the modern figurative usage, not the archaic *literal* one), is *to form the basis or foundation of : strengthen, **support***. And their (hand-picked, I'm sure) example usage is ***facts and statistics subtly undergird his commentary***. To my mind, the word ***subtly*** there completely rules out the possibility that his commentary is actually ***based*** on those facts and statistics - they just provide ***additional support***.

Answer (score 0):

[Americans *used* to actually prefer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=undergirds%20the%20argument%2Cunderpins%20the%20argument&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3) ***undergird*** to ***underpin*** in this context...

[image]

...but [Brits](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=undergirds%20the%20argument%2Cunderpins%20the%20argument&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) have always stuck with ***underpin...***

[image]

---

Just [to drive home the demise](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=undergirded%2Cunderpinned&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) of ***-gird*** relative to ***-pin*** here...

[image]

---

TL;DR: You will still encounter figurative *undergird*. But it's rapidly dying out. Avoid it.

Comment: "Avoid it." Why? Should we avoid all the rare words?

Comment: Anyone who needs to ask about such things here is obviously a "learner", and we're talking here about a usage that barely even *existed* until well after WW2. But even in that short time, my chart makes it obvious that ***undergirding arguments*** never really gained traction. Effectively, it's a "failed coinage", rather than part of our rich linguistic heritage that we might need to fully appreciate our *literary* history. And there's absolutely no chance that using ***undergird*** in this sense conveys anything subtly different to ***underpin*** other than "speaker/writer is older American".

Comment: The Britannica Dictionary,

Comment: @user66974: The Britannica Dictionary just reinforces my point, in that they specifically list figurative *the moral **underpinnings** [=basis] of the administration's policies*. Whilst it's true that Google Books finds a handful of written instances of [*"the moral undergirdings"*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+moral+undergirdings%22), there are hundreds, if not *thousands* of written instances of [*"the moral underpinnings".*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+moral+underpinnings%22)

Comment: The Britannica Dictionary simply defines the term as “chiefly AmE, https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/undergird, The Cambridge Dictionary just says it is “formal” https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/undergird, only Collins defines the term as not very common. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/undergird - and your Ngram shows a divergence in usage between undergird vs underpin which is very recent. I do agree, as I said, the term is not very common, but not to the point of avoiding it, at least in formal context.

Comment: Defend it if you insist. but it's obviously a dying usage.

Comment: In AmE I don't find this term particularly uncommon or problematic. I think the overall Ngram Viewer results are skewed by the extreme unpopularity of the term in non-AmE dialects.

Comment: (I think the asker's usage is wrong, though. See my comment on the other answer.)

Comment: @alphabet: That's a ridiculous argument! My charts above only look at usage since WW2, so AmE pretty much swamps everything else anyway. [Here's my first](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=undergirds+the+argument%2Cunderpins+the+argument&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=20) chart (AmE) again, smoothed out a bit. And [here's the same for "ALL English"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=undergirds+the+argument%2Cunderpins+the+argument&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20). The basic pattern looks much the same.

Comment: Anyway, I'm not trying to persuade native Anglophone Americans to change their usage. I'm simply suggesting to *learners* that they should go for the up-and-coming new kid on the block. I should have voted to migrate to ELL, rather than put that advice *here*.